# How can I dismiss/pop a UIPageViewController after the last view controller is swiped?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

How can I dismiss/pop a UIPageViewController after the last view controller is swiped?
Basically want to make a tutorial style paging view with images, and to dismiss after the user swipes to the "next" page from the last.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(EmailTutorialViewController *)viewController index];


    index++;

    if (index == 5) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // this doesn't do anything
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: you can find loads of solutions already at stackoverflow. please dont overload it much.

Comment: I haven't found anything yet, which is why I posted.

Comment: [self dimissViewController] or [self.navigationcontroller popviewcontoller]

Comment: Where would you make this call?

Comment: in the method which will be invoked or called on "Next" button click

Comment: [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] in your ViewController class, or better ask your parent to dismiss the VC: [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]. You can of course animate or not and use the completion block.

Comment: i will make it more complicated, add an observer on your index and pop when the value correspond to the last one :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's simple solution I've used:

In

`- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;`

return empty controller for `index == 5` and add this `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` method:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers
{
    EmailTutorialViewController *viewController = 
                [pendingViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([viewController index] == 5) 
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: had to modify a boatload of other delegate methods, but thanks for the starter

Answer (score 0):

Within your UIPageViewController or viewController conforming to the UIPageViewControllerDelegate protocol:

```
// UIPageViewController.h
@interface UIPageViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger pageIndex;

@end

// UIPageViewController.m
@implementation UIPageViewController

/* ... */

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Start with animation from the presenting view/item.
    UIViewController *singlePageVC = [UIViewController viewControllerWithPageIndex:self.pageIndex];
    singlePageVC.view.alpha = 0.0f;
    if (singlePageVC != nil) {
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;

        // Add singlePageVC to the page view controller with the initial pageIndex.
        [self setViewControllers:@[ singlePageVC ]
                       direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                        animated:NO
                      completion:nil];
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIPageViewControllerDelegate

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger index = singlePageVC.pageIndex;
    // This will add a page before the current view controller.
    // Even if the index is 0, a new (dismissing) view controller will be added here.
    return [UIViewController viewControllerWithPageIndex:index - 1];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
       viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger index = singlePageVC.pageIndex;
    // This will add a page after the current view controller.
    // Even if the index is at your array bounds (i.e., 5), a new (dismissing) view controller will be added here.
    return [UIViewController viewControllerWithPageIndex:index + 1];
}

/* ... */

@end

// UIViewController+PageIndex.h
extern NSString * const UIViewControllerShouldDismissFromPageViewControllerNotification;

@interface UIViewController (PageIndex)

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger pageIndex;

- (instancetype)initWithPageIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex;
+ (instancetype)viewControllerWithPageIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex;

@end

// UIViewController+PageIndex.m
NSString * const UIViewControllerShouldDismissFromPageViewControllerNotification = @"UIViewControllerShouldDismissFromPageViewControllerNotification";

@implementation UIViewController (PageIndex)

// Initialize with the current item's index.
- (instancetype)initWithPageIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _pageIndex = pageIndex;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)viewControllerWithPageIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithPageIndex:pageIndex];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Check for pageIndex out of bounds of your array.
    // This will be either less than 0 or greater or equal to your array count.
    if (self.pageIndex < 0 || self.pageIndex >= array.count) { // Replace with your global or passed array here.
        // Post dismiss notification here.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        postNotificationName:UIViewControllerShouldDismissFromPageViewControllerNotification
        object:nil];
        return;
    }
}

@end

// View controller than manages your UIPageViewController.

@implementation YourViewController

/* ... */

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissPageViewController:)
    name:UIViewControllerShouldDismissFromPageViewControllerNotification
    object:nil];
}

- (void)dismissPageViewController:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Dismiss your page view controllers here.
    [self.pageViewController dismissViewController];
    self.pageViewController = nil;

    // Or remove the page view controllers from its parent view controller,
    [self.pageViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self.pageViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    // Or its view from its super view.
    [self.pageViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.pageViewController = nil;
}

/* ... */

@end
```